# javascript - What split(" ") method gives at the last index of array when string is ending with space character?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string, user-input

I have an issue with `split()` method when I define space `" "` as a splitting character when I use it on the string which ends with space. For my function, it is very important for an array which is created by `split()` to contain only words with two or more characters and not spaces and empty values.

EXAMPLE: What is the value of the last index in the array after `split(" ")` is done to the sentence "This is my home ", which has space at the end?

Comment: Use filter after splitting to remove empty values

Comment: you can trim your string before splitting it, that will remove trailing whitespace

Comment: Can you illustrate your problem with an input, an output, and the output you really needed? Because what should "this is a sentence" become?  ["this","is","sentence"]? (and please update your post with that information, don't add that detailed explanation as a comment)

Comment: What about double spaces in the middle of the string?

Comment: so trim it if you do not want trailing spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `String.prototype.trim` function to remove the white spaces at the begining and at the end of the string, before `split`(ting) the string:

```
var result = str.trim().split(' ');
```

More about [String.prototype.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim) function.

Comment: This is just what I needed! Works like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's the intended behaviour of `split`. Filter your results afterwards.

```
var arr = str.split(' ').filter( function( word ) {
    return word.length > 2
})
```

ES6:

```
var arr = str.split(' ').filter( word => word.length > 2 );
```

Comment: This `word`, is it predefined in JS, or you can put anything you want there?

Comment: More or less. It’s an arrow function and `word` is the name of its parameter. I’ve written it without the arrow function, which might look more familiar to you.